# Good guide to test a new 'factor' and control using other factors in regression model (like Fama French)?

Tags: regression, factor-models, reference-request, fama-french

I'm trying to get a better understanding of different ways one can test a new factor within the Fama-French framework?

For example, some questions I have are:

1. I want to test if Warren Buffet is in a stock, does that lead to outperformance?  How would I test this controlling for the characteristics of that stock?  Do I just create another factor where it's a portfolio of Buffet's stocks minus everything else?  What happens if I have to drop stocks out of the portfolio and rebalance monthly?
2. What do I use for the universe?  SP500?  Russell2000? To construct SMB and HML
3. Is the model usually built using MONTHLY returns?

Etcc.. like a lay man's guide would be useful.

Thanks!

Comment: The question is extremely broad, depends on your available data, objective, and, frankly, experience. Have you tried replicating HML or SMB (to learn how it's done) before constructing your own factor?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.